# Whats the time complexity of the following?

Tags: time-complexity

I've seen many questions of this type but I still can't get the while iteration clear.

```
for i=1...n
 for j=1..i
  k=n
  while (k>2)
   k=k^(1/3)
```

Answer (score 5):

The two `for` loops are `O(n^2)` combined, and the inner loop is `O(log2(log2(n))` [*]. Thus the overall complexity is `O(n^2*log2(log2(n)))`.

To find the number of iterations `m` of the inner loop, we need to solve the following for `m`:

```
n = 2^(3^m)
```

This gives `log3(log2(n))`, which is the same as `O(log2(log2(n))` (using the same log base for consistency).

[*] Assuming that, in your notation, `k^(1/3)` is the cube root of `k`.

Comment: Additional explanation required why `O(log n)` it is not obvious.

Comment: @talex: It follows directly from the definition of the logarithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm

Comment: how `k^(1/3n) < 2` lead to n = O(log k)? If `k = k/3` then it obvious.

Comment: @talex: I've edited the answer to include a tighter big-Oh bound.

Comment: How you come to `n = 2^(3^m)` equation? loop is effectively search for  n for which `(k^(1/3))^n` is less then 2. `(k^(1/3))^n` is `k^(1/(3*n))`. So we need to solve `2>k^(1/(3*n))`. =>`logK(2)>1/(3*n)` => `ln(2)/ln(k) = 1/(3*n)` => `ln(2)*3*n = ln(k)` => (omiting constants) `n = O(ln(k))`. So you initia guess was right. PS: logK is log base k

Comment: @talex: I am pretty sure both of my upper bounds are correct. I have to run, so at the moment don't have time to look for an error in your reasoning. Why don't you write it up as a complete answer? If it's correct, I'll be happy to upvote it.